# changing number of outputs/classes in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my simple logistic regression with two features and two classes:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 2))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None,))
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(2, 2)))
p = tf.matmul(x, w)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(p, y))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
```

Everything works as expected at this point.

Now, my goal is to modify number of outputs/classes in-between training steps.
It seems that there is a way to modify the shape of weights:

```
n_more = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, ())
w_more = tf.truncated_normal((2, n_more))
new_w = tf.concat(concat_dim=1, values=[w, w_more])
change_w_op = tf.assign(w, new_w, validate_shape=False)
```

This also works. I can run `sess.run(change_w_op, feed_dict={n_more: 2})` to add two more classes and then continue running `train_op`.

The problem starts if I want to add bias term:

```
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(1, 2)))
p = tf.matmul(x, w) + b

# also for adding more
b_more = tf.zeros(shape=(1, n_more))
new_b = tf.concat(concat_dim=1, values=[b, b_more])
change_b_op = tf.assign(b, new_b, validate_shape=False)
```

If I run `train_op` before adding more classes - it works.
If I run change ops - `sess.run([change_w_op, change_b_op], feed_dict={n_more: 2})` they also work fine and checking on w and b individually shows that they increased in size. Even more, running `sess.run([p, loss], feed_dict={x: ..., y: ...})` also works and returns predictions for more classes.

**The only thing that does not work is `train_op`!**

It gives this error (3 in the shape correspond to the number of examples in passed x and y values):

```
....
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [3,4] vs. [1,2]
 [[Node: gradients/add_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](gradients/add_grad/Shape, gradients/add_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

From the traceback it seems to be coming from `p = tf.matmul(x, w) + b` addition op, but somehow related to gradient calculation. As if the b term is still of shape (1, 2) instead of (1, 4). Although evaluating `b` separately does return shape (1, 4) array.

What am I doing wrong here? Why changing `w` does not cause problems but changing `b` does. Is this a bug?

Comment: can you post complete stack trace and reproducible example? On the surface this sounds like you are computing gradient of the old formula instead of the new one

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I think you saw the full stack trace on github TF issue, let me know if that's not true.

Comment: I agree that it looks like the change of shapes does not propagate to all calculations, especially not for gradients. 
My confusion is that it does propagate for `w` when I use only tf.matmul, and it does update the weights properly and learns new classes. But that does not work when I add bias term as an tf.add op.
So why does it work for one op and does not work for the other?

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the number of classes while training. If that happens, you have to create a new model for the given classes and re-train from it.

Comment: Creating new model is slow. What if new classes appear on every new batch? I'm doing online/incremental learning.